# Uninstalling HyperV from Windows 8

Tags: vmware-workstation, hyper-v

Let me be the first to say that I love that my copy of Win8 Pro comes automatically installed with HyperV.  Unfortunately, I use Workstation instead and have been unable to figure out how to uninstall HyperV(Workstation will not install with HyperV installed).

Is it possible to uninstall this from Windows 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try launching:

appwiz.cpl and then going to add / remove feature. Search for it there.

Bring up the Run box, command prompt, or Start Search and type "appwiz.cpl" without the quotes.

Once the Add / Remove programs dialog opens, click Add / Remove features on the left.

Find the Hyper-V add-in and *un-check* it.

In fact, a quick search [confirms this should work.](http://www.howtogeek.com/76532/how-to-install-or-enable-hyper-v-virtualization-in-windows-8/)

Comment: Hmm, based on the error I was receiving I was under the impression that it would need to be uninstalled, not just disabled.  That did the trick though, thanks!

Comment: @cloyd800 The process is essentially the same, but instead of checking the box for the Hyper-V add-in you un-check it. That will uninstall it

Comment: Found this answer today and I see that I had already upvoted it. Apparently this feature was enabled again after the upgrade to Windows 10.

Answer (score 11):

Removing the feature from the control panel menu didn't work for me. However the following command did. It needs to be run from an admin command prompt.

```
Dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Comment: Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr
y the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Comment: For Windows 7, use

`Dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualPC`