# How can I create a 64-bit virtual network with VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I can't find an option to install a 64-bit OS on VirtualBox. I have a 64-bit host, but I can't find an option to make a 64-bit guest, only 32-bit.

Help please?

Comment: Could you, please, post some screenshots? This would make it easier for us to help you finding the solution. Also, please tag your host operating system. And, what is the guest OS that you can't find an option for?

Comment: Questions on stack exchange should show that some effort has been put into solving the problem already, and that the problem has beenclearly identified. Generic questions like this do not show any such effort, just the need for a guide which can. most likely, be found by Googling the relevant terms.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving us much info to work with, but I'm almost sure you have to enable CPU virtualization features in your BIOS/UEFI setup.

Also, there are a lot of good answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/668006/why-virtual-box-wont-give-me-option-to-create-64-bits-guests).